# Gravity forms - send filled field to google tag manager

Tags: wordpress, google-tag-manager, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I’m sending data from Gravity Forms (Confirmation Type: Text) to Google Tag Manager and it’s working fine.
But I want to send one of the filled field but it doesn’t work, could it be because when Script is executed there is actually no form anymore?

Is there any solution for that?

My current code:

```
var customField= jQuery('#input_3_13').val();
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
window.dataLayer.push({
'event': 'formSubmission',
'leadId': customField,
'formVersion': window.location.href,
'formReason': 'Odszkodowanie lotnicze',
'formId': 'Odszkodowanie lotnicze 3',
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably that's a case.
You may add one more script to extract the field value when the submit form is submitted (before confirmation event) and push it to dataLayer. Then if the page wasn't reloaded this value can be accessed in GTM as a dataLayer variable and you can reference this in your tag that fires on `formSubmission` event.